# I cannot post my new articles on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Since yesterday I cannot post on Facebook I have only an URL without thumbnail, nor metas.

I think that is a problem with like button but any idea how to fix.

Strange because my old articles working normally! only I have problems when I write a new post.

Here is the Facebook debugger info:

```
Response Code: 503

Fetched URL: http://www.whitewolfpack.com/2012/02/bonnie-marris-wildlife-artist-of_4001.html
Canonical URL: http://www.whitewolfpack.com/2012/02/bonnie-marris-wildlife-artist-of_4001.html

Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code

Errors That Must Be Fixed
Missing Required Property: The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The og:title property is required, but not present.

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property: The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
URLs

Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/10150624491404835
Scraped URL: See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL
http://www.whitewolfpack.com/2012/02/bonnie-marris-wildlife-artist-of_4001.html
www.whitewolfpack.com
```

Answer (score 0):

**Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed**

*Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code*

HTTP Response Code: 503

For more information about response codes, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

**503 Service Unavailable**
    The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).[2] Generally, this is a temporary state.

Your might be in a load balanced environment where a bad server is still in rotation.